# How to convert xml response using curl into array then store in database using php

Tags: php, curl

**I am invoking PHP cURL method on a server and the response is XML type. cURL is saving the output (after removing the tags) in a scalar type variable. Is there a way to store it in an database so that it's easy to parse?**

```
<Response status="OK" responseTime="10">
<Results>
<wirelineServices>
<blockFIPS>360775908001027</blockFIPS>
<frn>0007556251</frn>
<providerName>Time Warner Cable LLC</providerName>
<doingBusinessAs>Time Warner Cable</doingBusinessAs>
<holdingCompanyNumber>131352</holdingCompanyNumber>
<holdingCompanyName>Time Warner Cable Inc.</holdingCompanyName>
<providerURL>www.timewarnercable.com</providerURL>
<technologies>
<technologyCode>40</technologyCode>
<typicalDownloadSpeed>0</typicalDownloadSpeed>
<typicalUploadSpeed>0</typicalUploadSpeed>
<maximumAdvertisedDownloadSpeed>9</maximumAdvertisedDownloadSpeed>
<maximumAdvertisedUploadSpeed>5</maximumAdvertisedUploadSpeed>
<overallQuality>1</overallQuality>
<speedQuality>1.00</speedQuality>
<technologyQuality>3.00</technologyQuality>
<providerQuality>3.00</providerQuality>
<downloadQuality>1.00</downloadQuality>
<uploadQuality>1.00</uploadQuality>
<maximumProviderScore>3.00</maximumProviderScore>
<maximumTechnologyScore>3.00</maximumTechnologyScore>
<maximumSpeedScore>2.00</maximumSpeedScore>
<maximumDownloadScore>2.00</maximumDownloadScore>
<maximumUploadScore>2.00</maximumUploadScore>
</technologies>
</wirelineServices>
<wirelineServices>
<blockFIPS>360775908001027</blockFIPS>
<frn>0003469442</frn>
<providerName>Verizon New York Inc.</providerName>
<doingBusinessAs>Verizon New York</doingBusinessAs>
<holdingCompanyNumber>131425</holdingCompanyNumber>
<holdingCompanyName>Verizon Communications Inc.</holdingCompanyName>
<providerURL>www.connecttoverizon.com</providerURL>
<technologies>
<technologyCode>10</technologyCode>
<typicalDownloadSpeed>0</typicalDownloadSpeed>
<typicalUploadSpeed>0</typicalUploadSpeed>
<maximumAdvertisedDownloadSpeed>5</maximumAdvertisedDownloadSpeed>
<maximumAdvertisedUploadSpeed>3</maximumAdvertisedUploadSpeed>
<overallQuality>1</overallQuality>
<speedQuality>1.00</speedQuality>
<technologyQuality>2.00</technologyQuality>
<providerQuality>2.00</providerQuality>
<downloadQuality>0.00</downloadQuality>
<uploadQuality>1.00</uploadQuality>
<maximumProviderScore>3.00</maximumProviderScore>
<maximumTechnologyScore>2.00</maximumTechnologyScore>
<maximumSpeedScore>2.00</maximumSpeedScore>
<maximumDownloadScore>2.00</maximumDownloadScore>
<maximumUploadScore>2.00</maximumUploadScore>
</technologies>
</wirelineServices>
<broadbandSource>
<stateFips>36</stateFips>
<organization>The New York State Office of Cyber Security</organization>
<organizationURL>http://www.cscic.state.ny.us/broadband/</organizationURL>
</broadbandSource>
</Results>
</Response>
```

**My ans.**

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $request_url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 130);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
            curl_close($curl); 


$xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$arr = json_decode($json,true);
```

Comment: `$xml = simplexml_load_string($response);` should parse the string XML and produce a nice parsed object, which you can then access properties of. Why would you need the extra step of running through the json_encode/decode?

Comment: Does your approach do what you want?  What exactly is the question?

Comment: i have to get xml response values and store it in database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this. Iterate through all the arrays to get all the values of wirelineServices. This will result in to 2 records. Insert all the values in a string and place the string in to an array.

Making the query for our DB. I Asummed you have a column for every value. And imloded the array with our string to get all records in to our db.

Ofcourse you need to change the table name and you have to use your connection data.

```
<?php
$xmlstr = '<Response status="OK" responseTime="10">
<Results>
<wirelineServices>
<blockFIPS>360775908001027</blockFIPS>
<frn>0007556251</frn>
<providerName>Time Warner Cable LLC</providerName>
<doingBusinessAs>Time Warner Cable</doingBusinessAs>
<holdingCompanyNumber>131352</holdingCompanyNumber>
<holdingCompanyName>Time Warner Cable Inc.</holdingCompanyName>
<providerURL>www.timewarnercable.com</providerURL>
<technologies>
<technologyCode>40</technologyCode>
<typicalDownloadSpeed>0</typicalDownloadSpeed>
<typicalUploadSpeed>0</typicalUploadSpeed>
<maximumAdvertisedDownloadSpeed>9</maximumAdvertisedDownloadSpeed>
<maximumAdvertisedUploadSpeed>5</maximumAdvertisedUploadSpeed>
<overallQuality>1</overallQuality>
<speedQuality>1.00</speedQuality>
<technologyQuality>3.00</technologyQuality>
<providerQuality>3.00</providerQuality>
<downloadQuality>1.00</downloadQuality>
<uploadQuality>1.00</uploadQuality>
<maximumProviderScore>3.00</maximumProviderScore>
<maximumTechnologyScore>3.00</maximumTechnologyScore>
<maximumSpeedScore>2.00</maximumSpeedScore>
<maximumDownloadScore>2.00</maximumDownloadScore>
<maximumUploadScore>2.00</maximumUploadScore>
</technologies>
</wirelineServices>
<wirelineServices>
<blockFIPS>360775908001027</blockFIPS>
<frn>0003469442</frn>
<providerName>Verizon New York Inc.</providerName>
<doingBusinessAs>Verizon New York</doingBusinessAs>
<holdingCompanyNumber>131425</holdingCompanyNumber>
<holdingCompanyName>Verizon Communications Inc.</holdingCompanyName>
<providerURL>www.connecttoverizon.com</providerURL>
<technologies>
<technologyCode>10</technologyCode>
<typicalDownloadSpeed>0</typicalDownloadSpeed>
<typicalUploadSpeed>0</typicalUploadSpeed>
<maximumAdvertisedDownloadSpeed>5</maximumAdvertisedDownloadSpeed>
<maximumAdvertisedUploadSpeed>3</maximumAdvertisedUploadSpeed>
<overallQuality>1</overallQuality>
<speedQuality>1.00</speedQuality>
<technologyQuality>2.00</technologyQuality>
<providerQuality>2.00</providerQuality>
<downloadQuality>0.00</downloadQuality>
<uploadQuality>1.00</uploadQuality>
<maximumProviderScore>3.00</maximumProviderScore>
<maximumTechnologyScore>2.00</maximumTechnologyScore>
<maximumSpeedScore>2.00</maximumSpeedScore>
<maximumDownloadScore>2.00</maximumDownloadScore>
<maximumUploadScore>2.00</maximumUploadScore>
</technologies>
</wirelineServices>
<broadbandSource>
<stateFips>36</stateFips>
<organization>The New York State Office of Cyber Security</organization>
<organizationURL>http://www.cscic.state.ny.us/broadband/</organizationURL>
</broadbandSource>
</Results>
</Response>';




$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlstr);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$arrays = json_decode($json,true);


//this is what your array looks like
echo "<pre>";
print_r($arrays);


$counter = 0;

// get all values inside wirelineServices
foreach($arrays['Results']['wirelineServices'] AS $nbr => $arr){

      //start of the input string
      $insert[$counter] = "(";

      //iterate through $arr
      foreach($arr AS $key => $value){

            //if value is array iterate through $value
            if(is_array($value)){
                  foreach($value AS $key2 => $value2){
                        $insert[$counter] .= "'" . $value2 . "', ";
                  } 
            } else {                  
                  $insert[$counter] .= "'" . $value . "', ";            
            }
      }

      //remove last ', ' from string.
      $insert[$counter] = substr($insert[$counter], 0, -2) . ")";

      //start new string
      $counter++;

$sql = "INSERT INTO `table` (`blockFIPS`, `frn`,`providerName`,`doingBusinessAs`,`holdingCompanyNumber`,`holdingCompanyName`,`providerURL`,`technologyCode`,`typicalDownloadSpeed`,`typicalUploadSpeed`,`maximumAdvertisedDownloadSpeed`,
      `maximumAdvertisedUploadSpeed`,`overallQuality`,`speedQuality`,`technologyQuality`,`providerQuality`,`downloadQuality`,`uploadQuality`,`maximumProviderScore`,`maximumTechnologyScore`,`maximumSpeedScore`,`maximumDownloadScore`,
      `maximumUploadScore`) VALUES " . implode(",",$insert); . "";

if (mysqli_query($connect, $sql)) {
      echo 'Records created successfull';
} else {
      echo $sql . '"<br>"' . mysqli_error($connect);
}

?>
```

Comment: it's working fine but i have to create separate  variable for separate value is it possible?..thanks for help me

Comment: Ofcourse that is possible, The code above is building a string out of loose values. which value do you need??